# Error trying to cap deploy:migrations with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Trying to deploy a rails app to a remote server.

I keep getting this error and can't understand how to solve the issue.

Here's the console log:

```
D:\>cap deploy:migrations
  * ←[32m2013-03-11 01:15:33 executing `deploy:migrations'←[0m
  * ←[32m2013-03-11 01:15:33 executing `deploy:update_code'←[0m
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    ←[33mexecuting locally: "git ls-remote root@NNN.NNN.131.4:myAppName.git mast
er"←[0m
root@NNN.NNN.131.4's password:
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 11708ms←[0m
  * ←[33mexecuting "if [ -d /home/root/myAppName/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /
home/root/myAppName/shared/cached-copy && git fetch  origin && git fetch --tags
 origin && git reset  --hard eba696f2195d19adba5fc7730828a69e7bfc3e9d && git cle
an  -d -x -f; else git clone root@NNN.NNN.131.4:myAppName.git /home/root/2antica
fe/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/root/myAppName/shared/cached-copy && git check
out -b deploy eba696f2195d19adba5fc7730828a69e7bfc3e9d; fi"←[0m
    servers: ["NNN.NNN.131.4"]
Password:
    [NNN.NNN.131.4] executing command
 ** [NNN.NNN.131.4 :: out] Cloning into '/home/root/myAppName/shared/cached-copy
'...
 ** [NNN.NNN.131.4 :: err] Host key verification failed.
 ** [NNN.NNN.131.4 :: err] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 1171ms←[0m
failed: "sh -c 'if [ -d /home/root/myAppName/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home
/root/myAppName/shared/cached-copy && git fetch  origin && git fetch --tags  ori
gin && git reset  --hard eba696f2195d19adba5fc7730828a69e7bfc3e9d && git clean
-d -x -f; else git clone root@NNN.NNN.131.4:myAppName.git /home/root/myAppName/s
hared/cached-copy && cd /home/root/myAppName/shared/cached-copy && git checkout
-b deploy eba696f2195d19adba5fc7730828a69e7bfc3e9d; fi'" on NNN.NNN.131.4
```

Here's my deploy.rb:

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
set :user, 'root'
set :domain, 'NNN.NNN.131.4'
set :application, 'myAppName'

set :repository,  "#{user}@#{domain}:#{application}.git"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/myAppName"

role :app, domain
role :web, domain
role :db, domain, :primary => true

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :scm, 'git'
set :branch, 'master'
set :scm_verbose, true
set :use_sudo, false
set :rails_env, :production

namespace :deploy do
  desc "cause Passenger to initiate a restart"
  task :restart do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end
  desc "reload the database with seed data"
  task :seed do
    run "cd #{current_path}; rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
  end
end
```

Considering the error is raised during cap deploy:migrations, maybe it's a db error? What can be wrong? The deployment db is mysql 5.5, and it is properly mentioned in database.yml.

Edit 1: 
Manually cloned the repository to the server.Excluded the output to save space.

Edit 2:

Adding this to deploy.rb:

```
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```

Has helped a bit. The command still fails, but leaves a much longer log:

```
D:\>cap deploy:migrations
  * ←[32m2013-03-11 02:24:54 executing `deploy:migrations'←[0m
  * ←[32m2013-03-11 02:24:54 executing `deploy:update_code'←[0m
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    ←[33mexecuting locally: "git ls-remote root@NNN.NNN.131.4:myAppName.git mast
er"←[0m
root@NNN.NNN.131.4's password:
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 12717ms←[0m
  * ←[33mexecuting "if [ -d /home/root/myAppName/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /
home/root/myAppName/shared/cached-copy && git fetch  origin && git fetch --tags
 origin && git reset  --hard 8b6824f3750031076be93783d7d9f66f53b0b429 && git cle
an  -d -x -f; else git clone root@NNN.NNN.131.4:myAppName.git /home/root/2antica
fe/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/root/myAppName/shared/cached-copy && git check
out -b deploy 8b6824f3750031076be93783d7d9f66f53b0b429; fi"←[0m
    servers: ["NNN.NNN.131.4"]
Password:
    [NNN.NNN.131.4] executing command
 ** [NNN.NNN.131.4 :: out] root@NNN.NNN.131.4's password:
Password:
 ** [NNN.NNN.131.4 :: out]
 ** [NNN.NNN.131.4 :: out] root@NNN.NNN.131.4's password:
Password:
 ** [NNN.NNN.131.4 :: out]
 ** [NNN.NNN.131.4 :: out] HEAD is now at 8b6824f capping capistrano
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 23741ms←[0m
    copying the cached version to /home/root/myAppName/releases/20130310222546
  * ←[33mexecuting "cp -RPp /home/root/myAppName/shared/cached-copy /home/root/2
anticafe/releases/20130310222546 && (echo 8b6824f3750031076be93783d7d9f66f53b0b4
29 > /home/root/myAppName/releases/20130310222546/REVISION)"←[0m
    servers: ["NNN.NNN.131.4"]
    [NNN.NNN.131.4] executing command
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 772ms←[0m
  * ←[32m2013-03-11 02:25:47 executing `deploy:finalize_update'←[0m
  * ←[33mexecuting "chmod -R -- g+w /home/root/myAppName/releases/20130310222546
 && rm -rf -- /home/root/myAppName/releases/20130310222546/public/system && mkdi
r -p -- /home/root/myAppName/releases/20130310222546/public/ && ln -s -- /home/r
oot/myAppName/shared/system /home/root/myAppName/releases/20130310222546/public/
system && rm -rf -- /home/root/myAppName/releases/20130310222546/log && ln -s --
 /home/root/myAppName/shared/log /home/root/myAppName/releases/20130310222546/lo
g && rm -rf -- /home/root/myAppName/releases/20130310222546/tmp/pids && mkdir -p
 -- /home/root/myAppName/releases/20130310222546/tmp/ && ln -s -- /home/root/2an
ticafe/shared/pids /home/root/myAppName/releases/20130310222546/tmp/pids"←[0m
    servers: ["NNN.NNN.131.4"]
    [NNN.NNN.131.4] executing command
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 791ms←[0m
  * ←[33mexecuting "find /home/root/myAppName/releases/20130310222546/public/ima
ges /home/root/myAppName/releases/20130310222546/public/stylesheets /home/root/2
anticafe/releases/20130310222546/public/javascripts -exec touch -t 201303102225.
48 -- {} ';'; true"←[0m
    servers: ["NNN.NNN.131.4"]
    [NNN.NNN.131.4] executing command
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] find: `/home/root/myAppName/releases/20130310222546/p
ublic/images'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] : No such file or directory
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] find: `/home/root/myAppName/releases/20130310222546/p
ublic/stylesheets'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] : No such file or directory
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] find:
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] `/home/root/myAppName/releases/20130310222546/public/
javascripts'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] : No such file or directory
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 756ms←[0m
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * ←[32m2013-03-11 02:25:49 executing `bundle:install'←[0m
  * ←[33mexecuting "ls -x /home/root/myAppName/releases"←[0m
    servers: ["NNN.NNN.131.4"]
    [NNN.NNN.131.4] executing command
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 721ms←[0m
  * ←[33mexecuting "cd /home/root/myAppName/releases/20130310222546 && bundle in
stall --gemfile /home/root/myAppName/releases/20130310222546/Gemfile --path /hom
e/root/myAppName/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"←
[0m
    servers: ["NNN.NNN.131.4"]
    [NNN.NNN.131.4] executing command
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] Cannot write a changed lockfile while frozen.
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 10392ms←[0m
  * ←[32m2013-03-11 02:26:00 executing `deploy:migrate'←[0m
  * ←[33mexecuting "cd /home/root/myAppName/releases/20130310222546 && bundle ex
ec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate"←[0m
    servers: ["NNN.NNN.131.4"]
    [NNN.NNN.131.4] executing command
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activ
erecord-mysql2-adapter` (mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/ru
bygems_integration.rb:205:in `block in replace_gem'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ac
tiverecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:3:in `<
top (required)>'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ac
tivesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ac
tivesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ac
tivesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ac
tivesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4]
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ac
tiverecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_speci
fication.rb:48:in `resolve_hash_connection'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ac
tiverecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_speci
fication.rb:39:in `resolve_string_connection'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ac
tiverecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_speci
fication.rb:23:in `spec'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ac
tiverecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_speci
fication.rb:127:in `establish_connection'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ac
tiverecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in <class:
Railtie>'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4]
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ac
tivesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ac
tivesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ac
tivesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `on_load'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ac
tiverecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ra
ilties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ra
ilties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ra
ilties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ra
ilties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ra
ilties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ra
ilties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ra
ilties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4]
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/releases/20130310222546/config/e
nvironment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ac
tivesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ac
tivesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ac
tivesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ac
tivesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ra
ilties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] /home/root/myAppName/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ra
ilties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:292:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tas
ks'
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4]
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
 ** [out :: NNN.NNN.131.4] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 6856ms←[0m
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/root/myAppName/releases/20130310222546 && bundle exec r
ake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate'" on NNN.NNN.131.4
```

capistrano, mysql2 and activerecord-mysql2-adapter are all in the gemfile.

Comment: It looks like verification is failing.  Can you ssh to the box?

Comment: Yes, I can. And the password I prompt in ssh and in deploy:migrations is the same. It's correct for ssh.

Comment: If you manually clone the git repository on the server (doing what Capistrano is doing), does that work or do you get the same error?

Comment: I have managed to clone the repository on the server, but it didn't change the output of the deploy:migrations. Adding the output to question.

Comment: Making progress on solving the issue, but stuck further on the way. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be this:

The server came with pre-installed Mysql 5.5 + Percona. I tried to use it, but having little experience, I probably haven't configured everything right. I ended up clearing the server, installing blank Ubuntu on it, then installing a basic PostgreSQL. Everything works now. Thanks to everyone for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

Enable SSH key forwarding by including the following in your deploy.rb

```
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```

But for that to work, you will have to connect to your deploy target using SSH keys, not password as it seems you are doing now.  Put the location of your private SSH key in your deploy.rb. eg.

```
ssh_options[:keys] = %w(~/.keys/my-secret.pem)
```

Also, you need to perform a cap deploy:setup at least once before you can perform the other cap tasks. The error in your log indicating that the application directory is not present probably means you need to run:

```
cap deploy:setup
```